# How to override LayoutImpl in Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to override methods of LayoutImpl in Liferay 7. I tried with service wrapper but there is no option for this class in the Service Name category.

How can I achieve that? Do I need ModelListener for this?

Comment: It always helps to [describe your goal](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A *service wrapper* is used to wrap *services*. Services in Liferay are usually named *...Service*, like `LayoutLocalService`.

Conclusion: The class `LayoutImpl` is no service - thats why you can't wrap it with a service wrapper.

You could wrap `LayoutLocalService` in a service wrapper, wrap the return values in your `LayoutWrapper` and unwrap the parameters. But that is troublesome and will prevent Liferay upgrades.

If you want to override `LayoutImpl` for fixing bugs - you should use an *Ext Plugin* for that.

A `ModelListener` can only change the content during updates of an article, not the implementation - I don't think that this will help here.

Comment: Does liferay 7 support ext? If yes, please give me the link of the tutorial regarding the same..

Comment: I didn't test it. But I would guess, as the ExtDeployer is still part of portal-impl. A short google search finds this link: [Advanced customization with Ext Plugins](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/advanced-customization-with-ext-plugins)